# Tkinter , 'module' object has no attribute 'Frame'

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

i write a hello world app in tkinter python, but i recive next message: 'module' object has no attribute 'Frame'

```
import _tkinter as tk
```

here is the error

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
    def createWidgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me)"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

        self.QUIT = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                                        command=root.destroy)
        self.QUIT.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

why this are happening?

Comment: I'm curious. How did you conclude that `import _tkinter as tk` was correct? Did you read it somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Tkinter` (`tkinter` if you use Python 3.x), not `_tkinter`:

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

---

According to [Tkinter module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules):

> ... The Tk interface is located in a binary module named `_tkinter`. This
>   module contains the low-level interface to Tk, and should never be
>   used directly by application programmers.

Answer (score 10):

Don't call your file as `tkinter.py`, rename if it is necessary.

Comment: That was the reason why my code was not working ... Thanks a million ...

Comment: Also, of course, this "bug" will bite if *any* of the files in the directory (not just the one being executed) are named `tkinter.py`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution here is to use the correct syntax for the associated Python version.

*Tkinter >> Python 2.x*

*tkinter >> Python 3.x*

Despite this, I had errors because I had called my file *tkinter.py*, and was presented with the error:

```
module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Frame'
```

Once I'd renamed my file to something else entirely, in my case I chose *tk-testing.py* it was fine in both Python 2.x and Python 3.x, whilst using the correct naming conventions above.

**Python 2.x**

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

**Python 3.x**

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the file itself shouldnt be "tkinter.py" **Once I'd renamed my file to something else entirely, in my case I chose tk-testing.py it was fine** this solved my problem